# Ubuntu shut down while updating?

Tags: installation, updates

Last night I was updating my Ubuntu 10.04 to either 11.04 or 12.04 (I'm not entirely sure which one it was, but I think it was 11.04) and I left it overnight to finish. When I came down in the morning, I noticed that the computer hadn't barely begun installing the updates! The update thing said that my computer was on the installation step, but it was still preparing the libc bin (or whatever its called) . It's like the first part of the step installing the upgrades. So, I stupidly restarted the computer, and when it rebooted, I got five options on a purple screen:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-28-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
Previous Linux versions
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

Long story short, not matter which way I enter Ubuntu to try and reinstall the updates using the root thing (it's like terminal) after I enter `sudo apt-get update` it basically said it failed to fetch every url link, and it then says:

```
W: Some index files have failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So, I entered `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and it says:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system"
```

I'm left like wtf, and I really just some guidance here. I just got this laptop, and I can not afford a new one if I broke this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot upgrade from an EOL version to another EOL version. 10.04 and 11.04 are both reached EOL and not supported anymore.

The best option you have now IMO , is to download the .iso of a supported version eg: [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) , create a bootable DVD or USB and upgrade Ubuntu through the installer window. You will see the option "upgrade 10.04 to 12.04"

[image]

Following links will help you in case you don't know how to create a Live DVD or USB and how to install Ubuntu.

- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [Installation from USB-stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
- [Ubuntu Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)
- [How to Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 From CD or DVD](http://linuxmoz.com/upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-cd-dvd/) (external link)

Comment: The problem is I cant boot up the computer at all and I have absolutely no idea how to do what you just explained to me. I'm only 14. Is there a youtube video or something that walks you through that?

Comment: If you cannot boot at all, then you have to create a Live DVD or USB through another PC. I will add some links at my answer in a few minutes.